# trying to solve a systems of equations with one inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I am trying to create a website that would run off this mathematical formula. I have tried to solve it but I got that there was no answer. I am only in pre-algebra and want a second opinion on if I got the equation right. thank you for your help!

$1.2=x-y$

$ x > 1$

$y > 1$

$x>y+2.3$

Is there a solution and if so how do you get it?

Comment: There are many solutions, e.g., $x=123.45$, $y=122.25$, $u=-1000$.  If you want to find one specific solution you will need more information.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no solution. Let us see:
$$y=x-1.2$$

It have to be:
$$x-1.2<x-2.3$$
It needs to have:
$$-1.2<-2.3$$
That is impossible. No Solution.

Comment: Where is the $u$ coming from? The system only has $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Before it was u.(Sorry)

Answer (score 0):

There are no solutions to this system.

$1.2=x-y\Rightarrow x=y+1.2$

Substituting for $x$ in $x>y+2.3$ we get:

$y+1.2>y+2.3\Rightarrow 0>1.1$

This last statement is clearly false so no solutions exist.